# dictionary value not printing when I press submit in tkinter program

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to create the below tkinter program:

1. **Select an option from each of the 4 optionmenus.**
2. Click **Submit**
3. Value from a dictionary where I have set up the keys to match the combination of the options prints next to Submit.

E.g. User selects '18-29, dry, acne, yes' from the options.
I have a dictionary in a separate python file with 200 pairs. One of pairs is:
'18-29, dry, acne, yes': 'Cetaphil'

The value printed should be Cetaphil. However, nothing is printing. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
from rp import recommendedproducts

age_menu = [ 
    "18-29", 
    "30-49", 
    "50-81",
    ]

skintype_menu = [
    "dry", 
    "combination", 
    "normal", 
    "oily", 
    "sensitive"
    ]

mainskinconcern_menu = [
    "acne", 
    "anti-ageing", 
    "dehydration", 
    "pigmentation", 
    "sensitivity/redness"
    ]

cleanbeauty_menu = [
    "Yes",
    "No"
    ]


# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x580")
root.title("SAVE MY SKIN")
root.configure(bg = "#32402f")

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


greeting = tk.Label(root, text = "Hello!", fg = "#faf2e9", bg = "#32402f",
                    font = ("Courier",20,"bold"), 
                    anchor = "w", 
                    padx = 30, 
                    pady = 10)

greeting.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)


instructions = tk.Label(root, text = "Fill in your details to get a list of "
                                     "product recommendations perfect for your specific " 
                                     "skincare needs!",
                        fg = "#faf2e9", 
                        bg = "#32402f", 
                        wraplength = 400, 
                        justify = "left", 
                        font = ("Courier",20),
                         anchor = "w", 
                        width = 60, 
                        padx = 30, 
                        pady = 10)

instructions.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)


disclaimer = tk.Label(root,text = "This is not intended as a subsititute "
                                  "for professional medical advice and should not be " 
                                  "relied on as health or personal advice. Always seek " 
                                  "the guidance of your doctor or other qualified health "
                                  "professional with any questions you may have "
                                  "regarding your health or a medical condition.", 
                      fg = "#faf2e9", 
                      bg = "#32402f", 
                      wraplength = 500, 
                      justify = "left",
                      font = ("Helvetica Neue",10), 
                      anchor = "w", 
                      width = 100, 
                      padx = 30, 
                      pady = 20)

disclaimer.grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)

ageclicked = tk.StringVar()
ageclicked.set("age")
agedropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root,ageclicked,*age_menu)
agedropdown.config(fg = "#faf2e9", 
                   bg = "#32402f", 
                   font = ("helvetica neue",20), 
                   anchor = "e", 
                   width = 27)
agedropdown.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10, sticky = tk.W)

stclicked = tk.StringVar()
stclicked.set("skin type")
stdropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root,stclicked,*skintype_menu)
stdropdown.config(fg = "#faf2e9", 
                 bg = "#32402f", 
                 font = ("helvetica neue",20), 
                 anchor = "e", 
                 width = 27)
stdropdown.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10, sticky = tk.W)

mscclicked = tk.StringVar()
mscclicked.set("main skin concern")
mscdropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root,mscclicked,*mainskinconcern_menu)
mscdropdown.config(fg = "#faf2e9", 
                  bg = "#32402f", 
                  font = ("helvetica neue",20), 
                  anchor = "e", 
                  width = 27)
mscdropdown.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10, sticky = tk.W)

cbclicked = tk.StringVar()
cbclicked.set("clean beauty")
cbdropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root,cbclicked,*cleanbeauty_menu)
cbdropdown.config(fg = "#faf2e9", 
                  bg = "#32402f", 
                  font = ("Helvetica Neue",20), 
                  anchor = "e", 
                  width = 27)
cbdropdown.grid(row = 7, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10, sticky = tk.W)

def helptext():
    print("Contact judy.tran@live.com.au for more information.")

def userresult():
    userage = ageclicked.get()
    userst = stclicked.get()
    usermsc = mscclicked.get()
    usercb = cbclicked.get()
    print(userage,",", userst,",",usermsc,",",usercb)

def userrp():
    if userresult in recommendedproducts:
        print(recommendedproducts[userresult])

def show():
    result = tk.Label(root, text = userrp()).grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = tk.W)

helpButton = tk.Button( 
    text = "HELP", 
    width = 27,   
    highlightbackground = "#32402f",
    fg = "#faf2e9",
    font = ("avenir next condensed", 20, "bold"),
    command = helptext
    )
helpButton.grid(row = 9, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10, sticky = tk.W)

submitButton = tk.Button( 
    text = "SUBMIT", 
    width = 27,   
    highlightbackground = "#32402f",
    fg = "#faf2e9",
    font = ("avenir next condensed", 20, "bold"),
    command = show
    )
submitButton.grid(row = 8, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10, sticky = tk.W)


root.mainloop()
```

**Dictionary**

```
recommendedproducts = {
    '18-29, dry, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, acne, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, dry, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, acne, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, combination, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, acne, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, normal, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, acne, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, oily, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, acne, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '18-29, sensitive, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '30-49, dry, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '30-49, dry, acne, No': 'Cetaphil',
    '30-49, dry, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil',
    '30-49, dry, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, dry, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, dry, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, dry, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, dry, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, dry, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, dry, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, combination, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, normal, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, oily, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '30-49, sensitive, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, dry, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, combination, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, normal, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, oily, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, acne, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, acne, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, anti-ageing, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, anti-ageing, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, dehydration, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, dehydration, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, pigmentation, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, pigmentation, No': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, sensitivity/redness, Yes': 'Cetaphil', '50-81, sensitive, sensitivity/redness, No': 'Cetaphil'
  }
```

edited function userrp() as:

```
def userrp():
    userresult()
    print(recommendedproducts[userresult])
```

resulted in **error**:

```
18-29, dry, acne, Yes
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/xx/checki.py", line 153, in show
    result = tk.Label(root, text = userrp(), bg = '#32402f', fg = '#faf2e9').grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = tk.E)
  File "/Users/xx/checki.py", line 149, in userrp
    print(recommendedproducts[userresult])
KeyError: <function userresult at 0x7ff01fd3c9d0>
```

[image]

Comment: Would need to see the logic and dictionary side of your code.

Comment: Do you get an error? (also, welcome to the site!)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still very new but it's been fun (and mind-boggling) so far. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't show up in the interface. I've updated with the entire dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to do a function call for `userresult()`.

`if userresult in recommendedproducts` Here you are checking if the function object is a key in the dictionary `recommendedproducts`. So what is happening can be compared to this:

```py
def foo(): pass

dict1 = {"a": 1, foo: 2}
dict2 = {"a": 1, "b": foo}

print(foo in dict1) # True
print(foo in dict2) # False
```

---

### Edit:

After taking a second look at the code, there are several things that occur that seem pretty obvious that the intended code is different from the one that is executing.

Let's begin with the structure, then work outwards.

Currently this is the flow of the nested function calls:
`show()` -> `userrp()` -> `userresult()`

```py
def userresult():
    userage = ageclicked.get()
    userst = stclicked.get()
    usermsc = mscclicked.get()
    usercb = cbclicked.get()
    print(userage,",", userst,",",usermsc,",",usercb)
```

`userresult()` does not return anything, by default this function will then return `None`

`if userresult()` would then be the same as
`if None` In other words, this if condition will never return `True` with the current code.

So let's fix that one:

```py
def userresult():
    userage = ageclicked.get()
    userst = stclicked.get()
    usermsc = mscclicked.get()
    usercb = cbclicked.get()
# We must return this string, so it will be used whenever the function is called.
    return f"{userage}, {userst}, {usermsc}, {usercb}"
```

Now we can use the return value for our if condition:

```py
def userrp():
    if userresult() in recommendedproducts:
# We want this function to return as well.
        return recommendedproducts[userresult()]
```

This function should now work properly, or as intended.

```py
def show():
    result = tk.Label(root, text = userrp()).grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = tk.W)
```

I've made a code snippet in hopes to clarify how nested functions, print(built-in function) and return statements work.

```py
def foo():
    print("foo")
    # This function does not return anything and will return a NoneType object
    
def bar(): 
    return "bar"

foo() # Prints foo.
bar() # Prints nothing.
print(foo()) # Prints foo, then prints None
print(bar()) # Prints bar

x = foo() # x = None, and prints foo
y = bar() # y = "bar"
print(x) # Prints None
print(y) # Prints bar
```

Comment: ohh that makes sense! I tried to replace with just userresult() as above  thoughand it had an error below about KeyError: <function userresult at 0x7ff01fd3c9d0>. I've added the error to the op

Comment: @joobs I've updated the answer, hopefully it fixes your code.

Comment: Thank you so much and for explaining the concept as well, I've learnt a lot from this. I did think my print was not correct but couldn't figure out what to do next! Thanks again!!